# Make an auto updatable VB.NET application

Tags: c#, vb.net, desktop-application

I have an application that is running fine.
I just want to add the auto update feature in that application so that the application can automatically download the updates and install it on the computer.

Comment: @SLaks, check @chaturs actual stats from the profile.  Accepted on 4/6 questions but oddly still has a 0% reported rate.

Comment: @JaredPar: When I left that comment, he had 2 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make your application a ClickOnce application.  It is a method of application deployment which has a very simple process for deploying new versions and having the client check for and install updates.  Here is a CodeProject articles which has a full overview

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/QuickClickOnceArticle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your application is structured and what kind of files you want to update.

But, basically, what you'll need is a "place" (like a WebService, for example), where your application will get the necessary info to update. Then it's downloading the necessary files and placing them in the correct folders.

I'd also advice you to write a new program, "updater", whose whole purpose it's to update your "main" program.

It's difficult to give you code on how to do this, as it it's more like a pattern that you'll have to implement.

**Edit** Also, as said by JaredPar, some platforms may provide tools to do this.